# Does Iran have religious protections for members of the Zoroastrianism faith?

Tags: iran, policy, religion, middle-east

I know Iran is majority Muslim and that some of the other faiths that can be found in Iran like the Bahai Faith have been [persecuted throughout its existence](http://info.bahai.org/pdf/GA05_Iran_resolution60.pdf).
I have also learned that Zoroastrianism is one of the [minority faiths of the nation](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/ir.html) and I want to know if Iran has any laws in place to protect the religious practices of Zoroastrians.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zoroastrians are recognised as a religious community. They are tolerated rather than protected. There is one seat assigned to the Zoroastrian community in parliament. Parliament is a relatively weak body, most power resides in the Islamic Guardian Council. Zoroastrians have been removed from city councils by the Guardian Council on the grounds that they are non-Islamic.

So Zoroastrianism is recognised and tolerated, it doesn't receive active support from the government and in some ways Zoroastrians are second class citizens.

(Wikipedia links [Religion in Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_Iran#Other_religions), [Zorastrians in Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrians_in_Iran#Post-Revolution))

Answer (score -1):

you need to protect something if it is under attack.

Zoroastrians practice their religion freely and since they are not a missionary religion (i.e. do not seek converts) they have no problem with the Muslim community.

They only part of their religion they can not practice is 'sky burial', which is prohibited by law on public health grounds.

a single case happened recently where the public elected a Zoroastrian to local office and the government canceled his election on the bases that he is not a Muslim, however that happens to Any person that does not follow the revolutionary-ideals of the Iranian revolution not only Zoroastrian.

Notice here, an Islamic majority elected a Zoroastrian, if they were second class citizen i do not think that would happen

However the public demanded his return and that what happened [Iran Lifts Ban On Zoroastrian City Council Member -Radio Free Europe](https://www.rferl.org/a/iran-lifts-ban-on-zoroastrian-city-council-member/29381709.html)

Comment: Good answer in the different perspective it offers. Could you expand on what is "sky burial" and if it is important to the Zoroastrians (i.e. if it it an integral part of their religion or an option one)?